# Fetch number of repositories using Github Api

Tags: javascript, rest, github, github-api

I need to fetch the number of  public repositories of a user using the Github API.
I know that we can get a list of repos using `/users/{username}/repos`.  This query returns a list of repositories.
What I want is just the total number of repositories not the entire list. If I try to count the repositories using `/users/{username}/repos` it works fine for the users that have smaller number of repositories but for users that have a large number of repositories , the API call takes too much time.
Is there any way by which I can get just the number of repos and not the entire list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting the list of repositories, you can get the user object and look at the `public_repos` field; for example, using the GitHub CLI:

```bash
$ gh api users/bewuethr | jq '.public_repos'
21
```

Answer (score 0):

The `total_count` field on the first response represents the total count of repositories matching, the response has your answer already.

Comment: where can I find this total _count field? Can you provide a small code snippet if possible?

Comment: search query with `type:user` https://api.github.com/search/users?q=type%3Auser